# How extract strings in first and last set of parenthasis?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have a file: queueN.txt, that looks like this:

```
uid=524357(aali95) gid=524357(aali95) groups=524357(aali95),611684(com_perkinsd),695433(bios420)
uid=524534(aalman4) gid=524534(aalman4) groups=524534(aalman4),426634(chem_shared)
uid=748146(abaner29) gid=748146(abaner29) groups=748146(abaner29)
uid=583567(abench2) gid=583567(abench2) groups=583567(abench2),875029(cs494_paka)
uid=570875(abhima4) gid=570875(abhima4) groups=570875(abhima4),875029(cs494_paka)
uid=603522(abokifa) gid=603522(abokifa) groups=603522(abokifa),750403(cme_abokifa),831682(vasphpc)
uid=747491(aboyap2) gid=747491(aboyap2) groups=747491(aboyap2),10(wheel),516955(acr_admin)
uid=500092(adavar2) gid=500092(adavar2) groups=500092(adavar2),10513(domain_users),426636(cme_shared),605853(cme_sarakad),831682(vasphpc)
uid=543988(adench2) gid=543988(adench2) groups=543988(adench2),545740(phys_hyowon)
uid=738525(aditya06) gid=738525(aditya06) groups=738525(aditya06),705095(acr_workshop)\
```

How would I extract strings only from the first and the last set of parentheses so that my output looks like this:

```
aali95 bios420
aalman4 chem_shared
abaner29 abaner29
abench2 cs494_paka
...
```

I am guessing the solution would be something of a loop with a sed command inside...

```
for f in `cat queueN.txt`; do cat ${f} | sed 's...'; done > queue.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid for loop with `cat`.

This `sed` should work for you:

```bash
sed -E 's/^[^(]*\(([^)]+)\).*\(([^)]+)\).*/\1 \2/' file

aali95 bios420
aalman4 chem_shared
abaner29 abaner29
abench2 cs494_paka
abhima4 cs494_paka
abokifa vasphpc
aboyap2 acr_admin
adavar2 vasphpc
adench2 phys_hyowon
aditya06 acr_workshop
```

We match using:

- `^`: Start
- `[^(]*`: Match 0 or more of any char except `(`
- `\(`: Match a `(`
- `([^)]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `)` and capture in group #1
- `\)`: Match a `)`
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `\(`: Match a `(`
- `([^)]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `)` and capture in group #2
- `\)`: Match a `)`
- `.*`: Match any text

And replace using:

- `\1 \2`: Replace with back-reference #1 then a space then back-reference #2

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- all lines have at least two sets of (matching) parens
- there are no instances of nested parens
- there are no standalone (unmatched) parens

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{ print $2,$(NF-1) }' queueN.txt
```

Where:

- `-F'[()]'` - define dual input field delimiters of `(` and `)`
- `print $2,$(NF-1)` - print 2nd and next-to-last fields

This generates:

```
aali95 bios420
aalman4 chem_shared
abaner29 abaner29
abench2 cs494_paka
abhima4 cs494_paka
abokifa vasphpc
aboyap2 acr_admin
adavar2 vasphpc
adench2 phys_hyowon
aditya06 acr_workshop
```

Comment: that's covered in the assumptions; if the assumptions are wrong then OP will need to say so *and* update the sample data sets to show such a scenario

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind 1 extra leading edge space :

```
 # safest approach

 mawk 'NF -= !!NF' FS='(^[^(]+|[)].+)[(]|[)]$'

                                               -or-
 nawk 'NF && --NF' FS='(^[^(]+|[)].+)[(]|[)]$'
```

---

```
# if you're very sure input has no blank rows

gawk NF-- FS='(^[^(]+|[)].+)[(]|[)]$'
```

---

```
# if you wanna also print the blank rows

mawk '!NF || --NF' FS='(^[^(]+|[)].+)[(]|[)]$'
```

---

```
 aali95 bios420 
 aalman4 chem_shared 
 abaner29 abaner29 
 abench2 cs494_paka 
 abhima4 cs494_paka 
 abokifa vasphpc 
 aboyap2 acr_admin 
 adavar2 vasphpc 
 adench2 phys_hyowon 
 aditya06 acr_workshop
```